# iPhoneMixerEQGraphTest crashes on device but not Simulator when Audio files are changed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, device

I am looking to launch Apple's sample code iPhoneMixerEQGraphTest with different audio files. I swapped out Track1.mp4 and Track2.mp4 with mp4 files I created. Both of my files are stereo, not mono. It launches and runs nicely in Simulator, however when I try to launch it on my device it crashes after about 10 seconds no matter what I do. Basically, I am wondering what I am doing incorrectly. It doesn't seem to be giving me any error messages. I have also tried different file types and names and changed the names in the code respectively. Thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the way the sample code works, but crashing without an error might be a memory issue. Are you trying to load very large files, or do you have a memory leak?

Try looking in the device logs in the Organizer (Window -> Organizer in Xcode), and try running your app with the Allocations and Leaks tools in Instruments.